# In an Excel PivotTable, how can I sort by multiple row fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, sorting, data-visualization

In Excel PivotTables, it's easy to sort, say, the rows by the major row field: There's a "Row Labels" column with a menubutton on the side, you click it, and you get sort options, just like in an AutoFilter column on a regular worksheet.

Sometimes, though, you use multiple fields for row labels; say two fields, major and minor. In that case, I'm not able to find any UI for controlling the overall row label sort order, or the intra-major-label order for the minor field values.

Is there such UI which I'm missing? Is it possible to set this sort order at all?

Note: Please don't suggest using a surrogate rank field composed from both of my real row fields. I realize that's a possible workaround in many cases, but I'd rather do this directly if possible.

Comment: When you click on that drop-down against "Row Labels", at the top of the little dialog that pops up there should be "Select Field", with a corresponding drop-down that has each of the data elements that you've put onto your pivot table rows.  You can select each of the different in that "Select Field" drop-down, and set the required sorting.  (Eg. you might have two levels in the rows - Year, and Country, for example - you can set "Year" to sort Descending, and then "Country" to sort "Ascending" ..... that's a simple example of how you might set the sort order differently for the rows elements

Comment: @Craig: I found it! Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @Craig: But then, it doesn't work... I mean, the UI is there, but the sort order remains wrong.

Comment: I've tried a few examples myself and the sorting appears as I would expect it to (based on what I've selected for the different row data elements).  Perhaps you'll need to provide some more specifics (and maybe screenshots, in this instance - even though images in questions are discouraged), so that we can see what's going on